# UILabel does not have a label named 'text'

Tags: ios, swift

On the line at the bottom that says self.pollResults1.text = "(percent1)% ((votes))        (percent2)% ((votes2))" I'm getting an error that says '[UILabel]' does not have a member named 'text'.  Could that be because I've assigned two values called self.pollResults1.text to the same IBOutletCollection with the variable pollResults1? That line with my IBOutletCollection is on the top.  Did I set up my IBOutletCollection wrong?

```
@IBOutlet var pollResults1: [UILabel]!

@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }
}

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT")  {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
        }

    let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
    let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
    let percent1 = votes * 100 / (votes + votes2)
    let percent2 = votes2 * 100 / (votes + votes2)
    self.pollResults1.text = "\(percent1)% (\(votes))        \(percent2)% (\(votes2))"
}
@IBAction func addVote2(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes2")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
        }

        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
        let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
        let percent1 = votes * 100 / (votes + votes2)
        let percent2 = votes2 * 100 / (votes + votes2)
        self.pollResults1.text = "\(percent1)% (\(votes))        \(percent2)% (\(votes2))"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

self.pollResults1 is an array of `UILabel`, not a `UILabel` - so as the message says, it doesn't have a property `text`.

What you want is something like -

```
self.pollResults1[0].text = "\(percent1)% (\(votes))        \(percent2)% (\(votes2))"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Now as it is, I'm getting an "expected declaration" error where it says query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT") the first time, though I have the entire query variable written the exact same way again later on and there is no expected declaration error.  What do you think could be the case?

Comment: You should delete the extra `}` that you have before `var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")`